# How do I filter through an array list and return results that match the filter parameter?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, array-filter

I have a list that I'm filtering through to return results that are either, `lessThan`, `greaterThan` or `equals` to a particular value. But the function that does the comparison returns boolean values.

`queryModifiers` is an object of key value pairs that specifies what key within the data set is being compared and also the type of comparison.

```js
const queryModifiers = {
price: "greaterThan",
weight: "lessThan",
}

const list = [
{
      '2104a7bd-5e78-49ce-a1f6-0699ac98f264': {
        additionalPrices: 0,
        clientOrderNumber: 'N / A',
        companyName: 'Test Company',
        completeDate: 'Invalid date',
        createdAt: '2019-09-08 16:41:43',
        createdBy: 'test@test.com',
        deliveryDate: '2019-09-14 16:39:25',
        driver: 'Robert Kaszkiewicz',
        dropOff: 'Avenida Callao 1234, Buenos Aires, Argentina',
        height: 23,
        isPreparingTrailer: true,
        isSmsSent: true,
        isTrailerReady: true,
        key: '2104a7bd-5e78-49ce-a1f6-0699ac98f264',
        notes: '',
        pickUp: 'Poprad, Slovakia',
        price: 1400,
        quantity: 2,
        trailer: 'einzeln',
        vehicle: 'Sattel',
        vehicleClass: 'Mega',
        vehicleId: '12313',
        vehicleReadyDate: '2019-09-27 16:41:22',
        weight: 123
      },
      '388113f5-3927-4fe3-80d5-f2fcf1c7cedd': {
        clientOrderNumber: 'N / A',
        companyName: 'Test Company',
        createdAt: '2019-09-26 18:32:18',
        createdBy: 'test@test.com',
        deliveryDate: '2019-09-20 18:31:45',
        driver: 'Michal Kucharski',
        dropOff: 'Logroño, Spain',
        height: 0,
        isPreparingTrailer: false,
        isSmsSent: false,
        isTrailerReady: false,
        key: '388113f5-3927-4fe3-80d5-f2fcf1c7cedd',
        notes: '',
        orderId: '',
        pickUp: '16671 Butano Place, Fontana, CA, USA',
        price: 0,
        quantity: 1,
        trailer: '2er Pack',
        vehicle: 'Sattel',
        vehicleClass: 'Standard',
        vehicleId: 'efgefg',
        vehicleReadyDate: '2019-09-27 18:32:08',
        weight: 0
      },
      '795e7531-8655-4e38-a576-e13483922607': {
        clientOrderNumber: 'N / A',
        companyName: 'Test Company',
        createdAt: '2019-10-07 14:59:28',
        createdBy: 'test@test.com',
        deliveryDate: '2019-10-09 14:54:44',
        driver: 'Pawel Marczyk',
        dropOff: 'München, Germany',
        height: 1150,
        isPreparingTrailer: false,
        isSmsSent: false,
        isTrailerReady: false,
        key: '795e7531-8655-4e38-a576-e13483922607',
        notes: 'alle fertig, vorher anrufen',
        orderId: '',
        pickUp: 'Soest, Germany',
        price: 5000,
        quantity: 10,
        trailer: '3er Pack',
        vehicle: 'Sattel',
        vehicleClass: 'Standard',
        vehicleId: '1121+23+24',
        vehicleReadyDate: '2019-10-07 14:55:19',
        weight: 20000
      },
] // list is an array of objects

export const handleFilterModifier = (value, compareValue, modifier) => {
    if (modifier === 'lessThan') {
        return value > compareValue;
    }

    if (modifier === 'equals') {
        return value === compareValue;
    }

    if (modifier === 'greaterThan') {
        return value < compareValue;
    }

    return null;
};

list.filter(
            item => Object.entries(queryModifiers)
                .every(([filterKey, filterVal]) => {
                    const compareValue = item[filterKey];
                    const value = Object.values(queryKeys);
                    const result = handleFilterModifier(
                        parseFloat(value),
                        compareValue,
                        filterVal
                    );
                    console.log(result); // result here returns boolean (true or false);
                })
        );
```

Where `value` is the parameter by which the list is being queried with e.g `100`

`compareValue` is the `data[key]` value from the list that corresponds with the parameter being compared.

and `modifier` is the comparison method e.g `greaterThan`, `lessThan` or `equals`.

I want result to return list items that match and not boolean (which are actually correct when matched with the dataset).

Comment: Have you tried anything, if so what have you tried?

Comment: @ruby_newbie No I haven't this is where I got stuck and need a headway. There's also a similar implementation but it returns values and not boolean.

Answer (score 0):

It's not *entirely* clear what you're asking, but it seems to be that the `console.log` you have is returning a boolean, but you are expecting it to return a value, since you are trying to filter the list?

But actually, you probably *do* want it to return a boolean where it is. It is inside of an `every` function, which itself is inside of a `filter` function. The way `every` works is each iteration should return true or false (and if there are any falses, the whole thing returns false), and the way `filter` works is for each item, if you return `true` the item is saved into the resulting array. They both expect a boolean return.

```
list.filter(        
    item => Object.entries(queryModifiers)
         .every(([filterKey, filterVal]) => {
             const compareValue = item[filterKey];
             const value = Object.values(queryKeys);
             const result = handleFilterModifier(
                        parseFloat(value),
                        compareValue,
                        filterVal
                    );
                })
        );
```

Line by line:

- `list.filter` : filter the list
- `item => Object.entries(queryModifiers)` : set each item in the list to `item`, and then get the key pairs of the object, `queryModifiers` (which you haven't included here, by the way)
- `.every(([filterKey, filterVal]) => {` : return `true` or `false` (i.e. keep or discard this item) if *all* of the `queryModifiers` key pairs sent into this function return true
- `const compareValue = item[filterKey];` : prepare a value
- `const value = Object.values(queryKeys);` : prepare a value
- `const result = handleFilterModifier( ... )` : determine a true/false result

At this point `result` should be true or false, signifying whether this key/pair of `queryModifiers` passes your test, and it *should be returned*, i.e. `return result;` If *all* of them do, then the `every` function will return true, which means this iteration of the filter function will be included in the result.

So basically:

```
const resultList = list.filter(
            item => Object.entries(queryModifiers)
                .every(([filterKey, filterVal]) => {
                    const compareValue = item[filterKey];
                    const value = Object.values(queryKeys);
                    const result = handleFilterModifier(
                        parseFloat(value),
                        compareValue,
                        filterVal
                    );
                    return result;
                })
        );
console.log(resultList);
```

Comment: thanks for this @tmdesigned but it doesn't completely solve the problem. I should have included what `queryModifiers` is. It is an object of modifiers which specify  which key within the data set is being compared and also type.

`queryModifiers = {
price: "greaterThan",
weight: "lessThan",
}`

Answer (score 0):

The section of code which returns boolean values is the following:

```
   export const handleFilterModifier = (value, 
   compareValue, modifier) => {
    if (modifier === 'lessThan') {
        return value > compareValue;
        }

        if (modifier === 'equals') {
            return value === compareValue;
        }

        if (modifier === 'greaterThan') {
            return value < compareValue;
        }

        return null;
    };
```

To say it in pure english: If the modifier is lessThan and the value is greater than the compare value it will return boolean true. If the modifier is equals and the values are equal it will return boolean true. If the modifier is greaterThan and value is less than compare value it will return boolean true. Maybe you need to have a good look at this code and fix it.